# tkinter packs in wrong window

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am creating the simonsays game and separating into 3 files. The table.py file contains:

```
from tkinter import *
import random



class Table:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, height=400, width=400) #tk.
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.dark = {'r':'darkred', 'g':'darkgreen', 'b':'darkblue', 'y':'darkgoldenrod'}
        self.light = {'r':'red', 'g':'green', 'b':'blue', 'y':'goldenrod'}
        self.squares = {'r':self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200,
                                              fill='darkred', outline='darkred'),
                        'g':self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 0, 400, 200,
                                              fill='darkgreen', outline='darkgreen'),
                        'b':self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 200, 200, 400,
                                              fill='darkblue', outline='darkblue'),
                        'y':self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 400, 400,
                                              fill='darkgoldenrod', outline='darkgoldenrod')}

        self.status = Label(text='Good luck!')
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

The player file basically has some methods on how the game should work. When I start the main_menu file(the one below) everything is running smoothly besides one thing. The status bar which is a label from the table file (which should be in the window of the game) is packed in the main_menu window. What is the reason for that? (I am still a beginner so dont be too harsh if it is stupid mistake ^_^ and thanks in advance)

```
from tkinter import * 
from table import Table
from player import Player

class Window():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x100')
        self.master.title('Simon says')

        self.label1 = Label(self.master, text = 'Welcome to the simon says game', fg='red').pack()
        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text = 'Start game',fg = 'blue', command =self.start_game).pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self.master, text = 'Quit game',fg = 'blue', command =self.quit_game).pack()

    def start_game(self):
        root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
        table = Table(root2)
        player = Player(table)

    def quit_game(self):
        self.master.destroy()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    my_main_menu= Window(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Side question is there a simple function in tkinter to use a picture for a background for the main menu?

Comment: You forgot to specify a parent  widget (the first positional parameter) when creating `self.status`.

Comment: Jesus, I have been stuck on this for at least 2 hours. Thanks a lot!